# Filter for a vpc_id value of None

Tags: python, boto

I have an environment that includes VPC and non-VPC.

This works as expected

```
filters={ 'vpc_id': 'vpc-xxxxxxxx',}
groups = conn.get_ec2().get_all_security_groups(filters=filters)
```

I get back all of the security groups for the specified vpc. However, the non-VPC/EC2 security groups have vpc_id set to None.

Is there anyway to use a filter to either list all security groups that are set to None or the are not set to vpc-xxxxxxxx?

The examples below produce no results and no errors.

```
filters={ 'vpc_id': None,}
filters={ 'vpc_id': 'None',}
filters={ 'vpc_id': '',}
filters={ 'vpc_id': False,}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use `filter` to search for empty values, because also the key does not exist at the Amazon-API. To analyze the API call and the response you can use the following line:

```
boto.set_stream_logger('boto')
```

You will see that the response does not contain a `<vpcId>` in XML. So boto can't set it and the value of this security group object will stay in `self.vpc_id = None`.

You should do a `get_all_security_groups()` and filter manually for `vpc_id == None` afterwards.